# Variance of random variable containing symmetric function

Tags: probability

Let $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ iid and $U = 2n^{-2} \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^{n} S(X_i - X_j)$ where $S$ is a function symmetric about zero.

I want to prove $ \text{Var}(U) = 2n^{-3} (n-1) \text{Var} (S(X_1 - X_2)) + 4 n^{-3} (n-1)(n-2) \text{Cov} (S(X_1 - X_2), S(X_2 - X_3))$.

Intuitively I got it by counting terms and using the Gaussian sum formula. My problem is to express this in more mathematical terms/formulas. Maybe someone can help?

Comment: Rewrite $U$ as $U=\frac2{n^2}V$ with $$V=\sum\limits_{i,j}T_{i,j}$$ with $T_{i,j}=S(X_i-X_j)$, use $$\mathrm{var}(V)=\sum\limits_{i,j}\mathrm{var}(T_{i,j})+\sum\limits_{(i,j)\ne(k,\ell)}\mathrm{cov}(T_{i,j},T_{k,\ell})$$ with $\mathrm{var}(T_{i,j})=\mathrm{var}(T_{1,2})$ for every $(i,j)$, $\mathrm{cov}(T_{i,j},T_{k,\ell})=\mathrm{cov}(T_{1,2},T_{1,3})$ if $i=k$ or $j=\ell$ and $\mathrm{cov}(T_{i,j},T_{k,\ell})=0$ otherwise. Finally, enumerate the number of couples $(i,j)$ and $(k,\ell)$ in the sums such that $i=k$ or $j=\ell$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elaborating on @Did's comment, from the bounds
$$ 1\leqslant i \leqslant n-1,\quad i+1\leqslant j\leqslant n, $$
or equivalently
$$2\leqslant j \leqslant n,\quad j-1\leqslant i\leqslant n-1 $$
we see that there are $2^{-1}(n-1)n$ pairs of $(i,j)$ and $(n-2)(n-1)$ pairs of $(i,j)$ such that $i=j$ or $k=l$ but $(i,j)\ne(k,l)$. From this it follows that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(U) &= 4n^{-4}\operatorname{Var}(V)\\
&= 4n^{-4} \left(2^{-1}(n-1)n\operatorname{Var}(T_{1,2}) + (n-1)(n-2)\operatorname{Cov}(T_{1,2},T_{2,3}) \right)\\
&= 2n^{-3}(n-1)\operatorname{Var}(S(X_1-X_2)) + 4
n^{-4}(n-1)(n-2)\operatorname{Cov}(S(X_1-X_2), S(X_1-X_3)).
\end{align}

Comment: I seem to be off by a factor of $n$ on the second term, however...